# Vue 3 computed keyword (Composition API)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Tmp Object looks like :

```
tmp : { k1: { k2 : { k3 : [abc, def] } }
```

Accessing k3 in setup looks like

```
tmp.value.k1.k2.k3[0 or 1].
```

I want to rename it to something like -

```
k3_arr = tmp.value.k1.k2.k3;
```

Inside my Vue single component setup function:

```
const tmp = (getting value from composable exported using ...toRefs from there)

// Already tried 1

const d = reactive({
         k3_arr : computed(() => { tmp.value.k1.k2.k3; }
}

return { ...toRefs(d) }


// Already tried 2 
const k3_arr = computed(() => { tmp.value.k1.k2.k3; }
return { k3_arr }
```

None of this is working.

Comment: The post is hard to read, the code and text are mixed. Please, format it carefully. It's unclear what the problem is. "This is quite big name" - is this the only problem? Because `(tmp.value)[k1][k2][k3][0 or 1]` isn't valid. If keys are really what you showed, it would be `tmp.value.k1.k2.k3[0]`. No multiple brackets.

Answer (score 1):

There are mistakes in listed computed properties. A value isn't returned from arrow function. There is no need to create `reactive` only to convert it back with `toRefs`.

It should be:

```
const k3_arr = computed(() => tmp.value.k1.k2.k3);
```

Comment: This isn't updating reactively.

Comment: Basically this computed is written like this. If it doesn't work for you, this means that there's something wrong in the code you didn't show. I.e. `tmp` or some nested values aren't reactive.

Comment: In composable: 
` const data = reactive({ tmp : {}, abc: {}, xyz:{} }
return { ...toRefs(data) }`  The tmp is getting updated reactively in the component but not the k3_arr.

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You didn't show how values are updated. Again, there is something wrong on your side. A computed works as expected, unless you killed reactivity somehow. It's written exactly as the answer currently shows, no more, no less.